# AttributeError: type object 'Employee' has no attribute 'empCount'

Tags: python, class, object

since I am new to python programming language and OOP concept.
I am exercising class's and object code. while I got this error

> AttributeError: type object 'Employee' has no attribute 'empCount'"

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount = Employee.empCount + 1 

    def DisplayCount(self):
        print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empcount)

    def DisplayEmployee(self):
        print("Name:",self.name," Salary:",self.salary)
```

code

```
emp1 = Employee("Zara", 1000)
emp2 = Employee("Brad", 1500)

emp1.DisplayEmployee()
emp2.DisplayEmployee()
print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)`emp1 = Employee("Zara", 1000)
emp2 = Employee("Brad", 1500)

emp1.DisplayEmployee()
emp2.DisplayEmployee()
print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)`
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in here? with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `Employee.empCount` is not yet defined at the class level yet and you are trying to access it. If your intention is to have a tap employee count based on instances created, then a class variable like this would do the trick. However it is usually not advised to share variables across instances this way rather advised to find a reliable alternative.

> > Note class Employee is inheriting from object this is called new style classes in Python.

```
In [29]: 
class Employee(object):
    empCount = 0

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.empCount += 1
        return super(Employee, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

    def DisplayCount(self):
        print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empcount)

    def DisplayEmployee(self):
        print("Name:",self.name," Salary:",self.salary)
## -- End pasted text --

In [30]: emp1 = Employee("Zara", 1000);emp2 = Employee("Brad", 1500)

In [31]: emp1.empCount
Out[31]: 2

In [32]: emp3 = Employee("Tes", 100)

In [33]: emp1.empCount
Out[33]: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `__init__`, you are trying to access a class variable that is non existent:

```
Employee.empCount = Employee.empCount + 1 
#                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ what's the initial value?
```

You need to define the variable at the class level in order to make subsequent updates to the variable, and python case sensitive so you need to fix your next error in the `DisplayCount`:

```
class Employee:
     empCount = 0
     ...

    def DisplayCount(self):
         print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)
         #                                     ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'Employee.empCount' variable.

```
def __init__(self, name, salary):
self.name = name
self.salary = salary
Employee.empCount = 0
Employee.empCount = Employee.empCount + 1
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to count the number of employees in the class of an employee. It is like each employee knows the total count...

You must have to have a kind of class that count the employees each time an employee is created or the simpliest way is to store employees in a list then look at the size of your list.

A solution may be:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

    def DisplayEmployee(self):
        print("Name:",self.name," Salary:",self.salary)
```

code:

```
employees = []
employees.append(Employee("Zara", 1000))
employees.append(Employee("Brad", 1500))

[e.DisplayEmployee() for e in employees]
print("Total Employee %d" % len(employees))
```

Resulting in:

```
Name: Zara  Salary: 1000
Name: Brad  Salary: 1500
Total Employee 2
```

Hope it is clear enough to help you.